# VS Code not discover the pytest tests in a class

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest

VS code version: 1.31.1

Problem:
The testcase can be discovered if I write the testcase without any class. If I put the testcase under a class,  it would not be discovered.  Why, and how to fix it
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pytest` follows a test discovery procedure which is described [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery). For the test functions/methods inside a class the rule says:

> `test` prefixed test functions or methods inside `Test` prefixed test classes (without an **init** method)

So renaming your class `DemoTests` to `TestsDemo` would work.